# Excel - Binding Serie Name

Tags: c#, excel

I am totally new with excel in C#, but I need to bind Serie name from a range or from a cell value. Following code is not working for me. Any suggestions ?

```
      Excel.Series serie = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
      serie.Name = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j], xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j+1]].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem giving equation like string such as ;

```
    serie.Name="=Tabelle1!$A$1" ;
```

So , serie name is binded automatically. For iterative calculation , I have used this form ;

```
            foreach (GraphFile file in files)
            {
                int count = file.Points.Count;
                Excel.Series serie = seriesCollection.NewSeries();


                //Bind serie name from excel sheet
                serie.Name = "=" + sheet_name + "!$" + (char)char_Value + "$1";
                char_Value += 2;

            }
```